# document.hasFocus in Opera?

Tags: javascript, opera

Does anybody know how to detect if the newly opened document has focus in Opera?

window.onfocus and window.onblur only help AFTER the focus is lost or gained, but not when the page is just opened.

And it's not good to assume that newly opened page always has focus: it can be opened in a behind tab.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/). Is adds two properties to document object: `document.hidden` (returns boolean value (true/false)) and `document.visibilityState` (returns string).

There is even a tutorial for this: http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/page-visibility-api-support-in-opera-12-10

p.s: To use this in other browsers - you need to add appropriate vendor prefixes.

Comment: Note that not being hidden is not quite the same thing as having focus. A window in the background that is partially visible is not considered hidden.